# Subset data to contain only columns whose names match a condition

Tags: r, subset

Is there a way for me to subset data based on column names starting with a particular string? I have some columns which are like `ABC_1 ABC_2 ABC_3` and some like `XYZ_1, XYZ_2,XYZ_3` let's say.

How can I subset my `df` based only on columns containing the above portions of text (lets say, `ABC` or `XYZ`)? I can use indices, but the columns are too scattered in data and it becomes too much of hard coding.

Also, I want to only include rows from each of these columns where any of their value is `>0` so if either of the `6` columns above has a `1` in the row, it makes a cut into my final data frame.

Comment: What language?! `R`? Add the relevant tag or no-one following R will see it. Please give a reproducible example, i.e. the structure of your dataframe, preferably `dput( head( df ) )`, or at the very least, `str( df )`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try `grepl` on the names of your `data.frame`. `grepl` matches a regular expression to a target and returns `TRUE` if a match is found and `FALSE` otherwise. The function is vectorised so you can pass a vector of strings to match and you will get a vector of boolean values returned.

#### Example

```
#  Data
df <- data.frame( ABC_1 = runif(3),
            ABC_2 = runif(3),
            XYZ_1 = runif(3),
            XYZ_2 = runif(3) )

#      ABC_1     ABC_2     XYZ_1     XYZ_2
#1 0.3792645 0.3614199 0.9793573 0.7139381
#2 0.1313246 0.9746691 0.7276705 0.0126057
#3 0.7282680 0.6518444 0.9531389 0.9673290

#  Use grepl
df[ , grepl( "ABC" , names( df ) ) ]
#      ABC_1     ABC_2
#1 0.3792645 0.3614199
#2 0.1313246 0.9746691
#3 0.7282680 0.6518444

#  grepl returns logical vector like this which is what we use to subset columns
grepl( "ABC" , names( df ) )
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

To answer the second part, I'd make the subset data.frame and then make a vector that indexes the rows to keep (a logical vector) like this...

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( ABC_1 = sample(0:1,3,repl = TRUE),
            ABC_2 = sample(0:1,3,repl = TRUE),
            XYZ_1 = sample(0:1,3,repl = TRUE),
            XYZ_2 = sample(0:1,3,repl = TRUE) )

# We will want to discard the second row because 'all' ABC values are 0:
#  ABC_1 ABC_2 XYZ_1 XYZ_2
#1     0     1     1     0
#2     0     0     1     0
#3     1     1     1     0


df1 <- df[ , grepl( "ABC" , names( df ) ) ]

ind <- apply( df1 , 1 , function(x) any( x > 0 ) )

df1[ ind , ]
#  ABC_1 ABC_2
#1     0     1
#3     1     1
```

Comment: @kaos1511 it is a `regular expression` so yes. Read `?regexpr` To get `XYZ` as well chain them together in the expresison like this... `grepl( "ABC|XYZ" , names( df ) )`

Comment: Thanks simon, how do i also ensure i only take rows which are >0 value for all columns that match the string i specify for column names?..will i need to see the dataframe that results and then specify manually?. If i see that there are 6 columns that match, should i say something like test<-df[ , grepl( "ABC|XYZ" , names( df ) ) ] and then test<-test[c(1:6)>0], will this work?

Comment: @kaos1511 that is a different question! It is bad form to keep asking question in the comments after the OP has been answered and it frustrates those who answer. Please ask a new question so everyone will see it. Thanks.

Comment: .@SimonO'Hanlon - I am using `grepl()` as `data <- data [, !grepl("Unique-",names(data))]` to remove column where column name starts with `Unique-`. I see that `grepl()` is appending duplicate column name with `.1`,`.2`,`.3` etc. Is it possible to use `grepl()` without affecting column name even if there are duplicates in the data frame?

Answer (score 47):

You can also use `starts_with` and `dplyr`'s `select()` like so:

```
df <- df %>% dplyr:: select(starts_with("ABC"))
```

Answer (score 21):

Just in case for `data.table` users, the following works for me:

```
df[, grep("ABC", names(df)), with = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 16):

Simplest solution, given to me by my statistics professor:

```
df[,grep("pattern", colnames(df))]
```

That's it. It doesn't give you booleans or anything, it just gives you your dataset that follows that pattern.

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Answer (score 15):

Using dplyr you can:

```
df <- df %>% dplyr:: select(grep("ABC", names(df)), grep("XYZ", names(df)))
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
df[,names(df) %in% colnames(df)[grepl(str,colnames(df))]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this (here, looking for variables whose name contains 'date', including all case combinations):

```
df %>%  dplyr::select(contains("date", ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide alternative solutions to subset **one** or **multiple** columns, based on @Simon O'Hanlon's sample data:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> df <- data.frame(D=runif(3),
+   ABC_1 = runif(3),
+   ABC_2 = runif(3),
+   XYZ_1 = runif(3),
+   XYZ_2 = runif(3)
+   )
> 
> df %>% 
+   dplyr::select(matches('ABC'))
       ABC_1      ABC_2
1 0.06445754 0.16957677
2 0.75470562 0.06221405
3 0.62041003 0.10902927
> 
> df %>% 
+   dplyr::select(matches('ABC|XYZ'))
       ABC_1      ABC_2     XYZ_1     XYZ_2
1 0.06445754 0.16957677 0.3817164 0.1922095
2 0.75470562 0.06221405 0.1693109 0.2571700
3 0.62041003 0.10902927 0.2986525 0.1812318
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off the above, I think it is the most flexible.  Note that you'll need to use dplyr, but that's not a terrible thing.

Advantage:  You can search for more than "`contains`". Here, I use "`starts_with`" for a relatively common string "ST".  Using "`grep`" here could easily have driven you mad; mad, I say!

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% dplyr::select(starts_with("ST",ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the [`tidyselect`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) options have been mentioned already. `contains` and `starts_with` work very well with this specific problem. For more complicated conditions/matching you can use `matches`, which will select columns using a regular expression match:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(matches("^ABC")) # starts with "ABC"

# case insensitive match
df %>% 
  select(matches("(?i)^abc")) # starts with "ABC", "Abc", "abc", etc.
```