# How can I specify columns in R to be used in matches (without listing each individually)?

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Suppose I have three columns of data (`sample1`, `sample2`, and `sample3`). I want all of the rows in which the letter `b` or `h` appears in any one of the columns. This works fine:

```
data <- data.frame(row_name=c("s1_100","s1_200", "s2_300", "s1_400", "s1_500"), 
                   sample1=rep("a",5),
                   sample2=c(rep("b",2),rep("a",3)),
                   sample3=c(rep("a",4),"h")
)

data

# row_name  sample1   sample2   sample3
# s1_100    a         b         a
# s1_200    a         b         a
# s1_300    a         a         a
# s1_400    a         a         a
# s1_500    a         a         h

bh <- c('b','h')
bh_data <- subset(data, ( sample1 %in% bh | sample2 %in% bh | sample3 %in% bh )  )

bh_data

# row_name  sample1   sample2   sample3
# s1_100    a         b         a
# s1_200    a         b         a
# s1_500    a         a         h
```

However, since I'm asking the same question about each column, isn't there a less redundant way to do this?

But in reality, we have over 800 columns and over 70,000 rows, and we will want to be able to choose as many or as few specific columns to search. Using hundreds of column names for example, just doesn't seem practical unless I script creating the R script.

Comment: `subset` isn't for programmatic use. Use `[` or even better use data.table syntax. Can't help you more without [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587334/subset-data-to-contain-only-columns-whose-names-match-a-condition

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the tip. I'm trying to make all of my questions that way now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 indx <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[,-1], `%in%`, bh))
 df[indx,]
 #   row_name sample1 sample2 sample3
 #1   s1_100       a       b       a
 #2   s1_200       a       b       a
 #5   s1_500       a       a       h
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 nm1 <- paste0("sample", 1:3)
 setDT(df)[df[, Reduce(`|`,lapply(.SD, `%in%`, bh)), .SDcols=nm1]]
 #    row_name sample1 sample2 sample3
 #1:   s1_100       a       b       a
 #2:   s1_200       a       b       a
 #3:   s1_500       a       a       h
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(row_name = c("s1_100", "s1_200", "s1_300", "s1_400", 
 "s1_500"), sample1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), sample2 = c("b", 
 "b", "a", "a", "a"), sample3 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "h")), .Names = c("row_name", 
 "sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your data.table example is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Christopher Bottoms No problem.  Glad it helped.